# ¿Como ocupar todos los casilleros en fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Una consulta para quienes hayan usado fullCalendar. Utilizo la version 3 de fullCalendar

Tengo el siguiente problema

tengo las fechas (las paso sin hora:minuto)
inicio 2020-06-01
fin 2020-06-03

Pero solo me esta ocupando 2 casilleros como se ve en la imagen, en vez de 3 casilleros [1,3]. No se porque sucede esto. Esto es cuando tengo habilitado el [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Entiendo que por defecto puede estar tomando como hora:mitutos como 00:00. 

El problema entonces seria que toma por defecto la hora 00:00, mi idea es enviar el día 2020-06-01 al 2020-06-03 y que pinte estos tres casilleros.

Entonces seria si necesita una configuración que tome el día completo, y no se si existirá dicha configuración. No lo he encontrado aun. Si me pueden ayudar.